# rails passing object to partials, then to another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

i was wondering how to pass an object to a partial, and then again to another partial?
im following the michael hartl book and this was an optional exercise but ive been super stuck.

if i have a..

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', object: f.object %>

<% end %>
```

from the book, it said to use a hash with the value equal to the object and key equal to the name of the variable we want in the partial. so that means in the _fields.html.erb, the key 'object' should exist and it should have the value of f.object

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: ?????? %>

<%= object.label :name %>
<%= object.text_field :name %>

<%= object.label :email %>
<%= object.text_field :email %>
```

but when i try retrieving the key, i get an error on the line

```
<%= object.label :name %>
```

it says

```
undefined method `label' for #<User:0x007f86000110c0>
```

why does it throw that? i thought i could reference the key as 'object'.

also, ive been stuck on what to replace the ?????? with. to replicate the error above, i took out the ?????? but it will throw another error from the next partial saying 'object' is undefined. i cant use something like f.object because f no longer exists. how can i get the value to pass onto the next partial?

thanks a lot = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're passing in `object: f.object`, and `f.object` is a `User`.  So then you try to call `object.label`, but `User` doesn't have a `label` method.  If you pass in `object: f.object, f: f` then in your partial you can call `f.label`.

Comment: that made total sense. thank you!
i eventually filled in ???????? with 'object' and everything works. thanks a lot!